# D (dlang): Can a function call in constructor & destructor converted to RAII in a object lifetime scope?

Tags: d

**Background:** In one of my projects, I have an abstract class with static interface to track resource usage of other objects. The Track class looks like this:

https://github.com/mkoskim/games/blob/master/engine/util/track.d

As you can see, other classes/objects call add & remove functions. Track class takes an object as an argument, and uses the information extracted from object to track usage: current implementation creates lookup table containing reference counters from class name. The output from tracking looks something like this:

[image: Tracked objects]

D has automatic memory management, so there is no point to track that. But these certain objects hold external resources - in this case, GPU side things like textures, vertex buffers and such - and I like to see that those are freed in correct situations, that is, e.g. switching to new level in a game works correctly, and there is no loose references left to objects in previous level.

---

**Problem:** Now, although it works, it is a bit clumpsy mechanism in my opinion. I need to add calls to class constructor & destructor to keep it tracked. In many cases, my classes have many different constructors, and I need to make sure that Track::add() is called once and only once during the construction phase. For example,

https://github.com/mkoskim/games/blob/master/engine/gpu/shader.d#L326

...here you can see, starting at line 334, one example of constructor "construction". The thing works, but whenever touching to constructors and their call tree, I need to be careful with the tracking.

---

**Question:** I am pretty sure D has some powerful tools to automatize these kinds of things. I have been mainly looking for mechanics similar to scope() to inject function calls to object lifetime (creation and deletion).

There is certainly some other possible solutions. One way, familiar from C++, would of course to inherit tracked objects from Track(ed) class, like

```
class Shader : Tracked { ... }
```

But I would not like to use that myself, as it would lead to problems if the class is anyways derivate from some other class. I am of course open for suggestions making that work somehow, e.g.

```
class Shader : BaseShader, Tracked { ... }
```

Another way might make composed classes, so that tracker object would be constructed & destructed according to its parent? Something like:

```
class Shader {
    ...
    private Tracked tracked = new Tracked(self);
    ...
    this() { ... }
    this(int) { ... }
    this(string) { ... }
    ...
    ~this() { ... }
}
```

Personally I feel it bit odd, that I need to attach extra, unnecessary memory blocks in form of Tracked object to other objects (as I only need to inject calls to parent class constructor and destructor).

What other ways there are?

---

If this felt confusing, don't hesitate to ask me to clarify the question.

---

Comment: This is hard to read. `Tracker.add(this)` and `.remove(this)` makes it look like object is being stored in the tracker until it is collected. Which makes no sense, because it can't be collected if it's still somewhere in the tracker.

Comment: That makes no sense, of course. add takes some info (currently class name, in future maybe pointer as identifier to track single blocks) from the object passed as argument, and uses it to track resource usage. The reason to track certain objects is that they hold resources from GPU side, and I like to see that those are freed in correct situations. I edit the original post to contain this.